# Get max Value with Distinct Foreign key Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-orm

So this is my Model.

```
class OrderLine(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name="Product",      null=False)
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=12, decimal_places=4, blank=True, verbose_name="Unit price")
```

Im trying to filter with Multiple Product Ids, One product can have multiple OrderLine with different Unit price.So how can i fetch one record of Max Unit price for Each product.

I tried

```
to_lines = (OrderLine.objects.filter(transfer_id__in=to_ids,product_id__in=part_ids).values("unit_price").order_by("product_id").aggregate(Max("unit_price")))
```

But it returns one over all the products.

Comment: What is the "exact" query that you have used? `aggregate(Max("unit_price"))` is not a complete version of your work, add the complete ORM statement.

Comment: @JPG updated check

Comment: Also, It is not clear what is your expected result - an aggregated result? a queryset?

Comment: @JPG in simplest explanation. `[{product_id:1, unit_price:500},{product_id:2, unit_price:300}]` which will be Max unit price for that product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a GROUP BY expression as

```py
from django.db.models import Max

result = OrderLine.objects.values("product").annotate(max_per_prod=Max("unit_price"))
```

This is almost similar to the SQL expression

```sql
SELECT product_id, MAX(unit_price) FROM table_name GROUP BY product_id
```

Comment: what can be done in the case of multiple `SELECT product_id, product_name`?

Comment: use `filter(...)` or `exclude(...)`

Comment: no i mean what if i want to fetch other fields as well with product id and Unit price as well. Normally we do add fields in `values` right ? but in this case if i add more fields in values than that product group by will not work i guess?